# SQL Query issue with subselects

Tags: sql, subquery

I have the following issue, I have 2 tables `USER` and `MESSAGES`.
The `User.ID` is the FK in field `MESSAGES.CREATED_BY` in the `Messages` table.

I have already joined the 2 tables with INNER JOIN but I would like to show in my SELECT the `messages.Created_BY` as `User.Loginname` which is a column in the `USER` table? A subselect  doesn't work as according to the error it is returning too much data.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT messages.id, messages.body, u.Loginname AS Created_by FROM messages m
JOIN user u ON (m.created_by=u.id)
```

Change field names messages.id, messages.body and user.id to those you have.